# ImageMagick script takes JPG and places on canvas but changes colour of JPG

Tags: imagemagick

I would like to take this logo and place it on a black background.

[image]

I am using the below script

```
convert -size 4000x4000 canvas:#000000 -background \#000000 background.jpg
composite rev.jpg -gravity center background.jpg output.jpg
open output.jpg
```

Which generates. As you can see the colours have changed and I cannot work out why?

[image]

Comment: Looks like the image is CMYK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the colorspace.

```
composite 03wp2.jpg -colorspace srgb  -gravity center background.jpg output.jpg
```

[image: output.jpg]

Answer (score 2):

Possibly a colour profile or are you using CMYK for the rev.jpg?

Try this which will shorten your code:

```
convert rev.jpg -background black -gravity center -extent 4000x4000 output.jpg
```

Comment: Nice alternative!